# spring json parsed Date contains hours

Tags: java, json, spring

I got a spring application that has uses an Entity like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
class Entity {
    private Date delay;
}
```

I pass the folloging json to an spring endpoint.

```
{
  "delay": "2022-05-15"
}
```

When I call `entity.getDelay().getTime()` I get `1652572800` this is the passed date plus 2 hours.

I want to receive the date with 0 hours because I need to compare the value to a value in a database that is stored without hours and minutes.

I you know how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the data type of value in database? Is it also timestamp or just date?

Comment: @Knu8 timestamp

Comment: Don't use a `java.util.Date`, use a `java.time.LocalDate` instead. The latter does not have hours of day, minutes of hour etc. but a `Date` always has.

Comment: Not answering your question. 1652572800 (seconds since the epoch) is Sunday 15. May 2022 00:00:00 UTC. If you’re in Germany (as your profile says), your time is 2 hours ahead of UTC at this time of year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Java 8 brought a lot of language improvements. One of those is the new
> Date and Time API for Java.  The new Date and Time API is moved to
> java.time package. The new java.time package contains all the classes
> for date, time, date/time, time zones, instants, duration, and clocks
> manipulation.

Example classes:

- Clock
- LocalDate
- LocaleTime
- LocalDateTime
- Duration

**Example using LocalDate**

```
public class YourDto {

    private LocalDate delay;
........//todo
}
```

**Find your day, year, and month like below**

```
   //Using LocalDate

    // Month value
    (dto.getDelay().getMonth().getValue()); == 5

    // Month
    (dto.getDelay().getMonth()); == May

    // Day
    (dto.getDelay().getDayOfMonth()); == 15

    // Year
    (dto.getDelay().getYear()); == 2022

    // Date
    (dto.getDelay()); == 2022-05-15
```

**Convert LocalDate to Milliseconds and Vice versa**

```
       // Convert LocalDate to Milliseconds
        long time = dto.getDelay().atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println("Time in millisecoinds = " + time);
        // Convert Milliseconds to LocalDate
        LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(Duration.ofMillis(time).toDays());
        System.out.println("LocalDate = " + myDate);
```

**As per @[Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v) suggestion.**

```
// Convert Milliseconds to LocalDate
    LocalDate myDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
```

> UTC is not a time zone, but a time standard that is the basis for
> civil time and time zones worldwide.

[Ref](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/)